# Optimal job interval algorithm

Tags: algorithm, intervals, jobs, job-scheduling

Let's say you have different jobs that you need to run on a regular basis (for example, you want to make API calls to different endpoints).
Let's say you need to hit two different endpoints and you want your calls to be as far away in time from each other as possible.

Example: You have two jobs, one is run once a minute, another is run twice a minute.

Solution: Start job A with interval of 60 seconds, wait 15 seconds, start job B with interval of 30 seconds. 
This way the jobs will run at seconds: 0(job A), 15(job B), 45(job B), 60(job A), 75(job B), 105(job B), 120(job A), ... making a maximum interval between API calls 15 seconds while maintaining the call frequency that we need.

Can you think of an algorithm for these cases that will give optimal start times for each job so that the minimum time difference between calls in maximized? Ideally this algorithm could handle more than two jobs.

Assume we don't need to wait for the job to be finished to run it once again.

Thanks

Comment: What to do for mutual prime intervals (for instance, 5 and 7) ?

Comment: Is it also possible that they can't be scheduled? - sounds like a similar problem to rearranging the letters in a word so they are k distance apart. Is it given, over what time interval the jobs need to be scheduled? like an hour 2 hours or so?

Comment: @MBo the start time for each job can be a float (eg. be in milliseconds). There might not be a perfect solution for each case. If the jobs will run simultaneously in some solution and that solution is the best we can do, this solution should be used.

Comment: @SamerTufail - The jobs need to run indefinitely

Comment: How important is the regularity?  For example how bad would it be in your case if you wound up with A runs at time 0, and B runs at times 20 and 40 seconds.  On *average* A runs once a minute and B runs every 30 seconds.  But in fact B runs with alternate 20 and 40 second intervals.

Comment: @btilly the regularity is important. A real world example of this question would be when you need to get some data from remote server which has different endpoints and you send a nonce parameter with every request (an ever increasing number, basically a timestamp). When two requests are being sent close to each other in time, they can arrive in a reverse order and one of the requests will be rejected by the server. We need to come up with a way to avoid such situations as much as possible

Comment: In that case I believe that an optimal solution will be NP-complete.  But you can come up with a reasonable approximation by scheduling from most frequent to least frequent in the best slot that you can currently find.  If you were willing to relax the requirement that the intervals be exact, it would be easy to arrange that you are perfectly maximizing the time between requests, but any particular kind of request would come at slightly uneven intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution if we allow the intervals to be slightly unequal.

Suppose that our calls are `A[0]`, `A[1]`, ..., `A[n]` with frequencies of `f[0]`, `f[1]`, ..., `f[n]` where the frequencies are all in the same unit.  For example 60/hour, 120/hour, etc.

The total frequency with which events happen will be `f = f[0] + f[1] + ... + f[n]`, which means that some event will be scheduled every `hour/f` time apart.  The question is which one will happen when.

The way to imagine this is imagine we have a row of buckets filling with water.  Each time we will dump a unit of water from the fullest bucket in front of us.

Since at the start we don't actually care where we start, let's initialize a vector of numbers by just assigning random numbers to them, `full[0]`, `full[1]`, ..., `full[n]`.  And now our algorithm looks like this pseudocode:

```
Every hour/f time apart:
    for each i in 0..n:
        fill[i] += f[i]/f
    i_choice = (select i from 0..n with the largest f[i])
    fill[i_choice] -= 1
    Do event A[i_choice]
```

This leads to events spaced as far apart as possible, but with repeating events happening in a slightly uneven rhythm.  In your example that will lead to every 20 seconds doing events following the pattern `...ABBABBABBABB...`.